# Is WebSocket supported in Firefox for Android addons?

Tags: javascript, websocket, firefox-addon, fennec

I need to find a way to communicate between Firefox for Android (fennec) and my Android service.
One of the solution was to communicate using WebSockets
Code:

```
var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8887/");
ws.onopen = function() {
  console.log("SENDING");
  ws.send("Hello messsage");
}
```

> 06-16 13:14:10.099: I/Gecko(8055): Message: ReferenceError: WebSocket is not defined

Is WebSocket supported in fennec addons?

Answer (score 1):

`WebSocket`s are available on Firefox for Android, however the usual `WebSocket` constructor is not available in `bootstrap.js` (Sandbox) or js code modules as these do not have a DOM window attached but are standalone JS.

However, there are two ways you can still create web sockets:

1. Use [`new Services.appShell.hiddenDOMWindow.WebSocket(...)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/Services.jsm). (Though, I remember there were talks at some point to remove the hidden window on Android?!)
2. Use the somewhat lower-level XPCOM Component [`nsIWebSocketChannel`](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/netwerk/protocol/websocket/nsIWebSocketChannel.idl) and implement [`nsIWebSocketListener`](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/netwerk/protocol/websocket/nsIWebSocketListener.idl).

BTW, you might want to check out [Remotely debugging Firefox for Android](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Remote_Debugging/Firefox_for_Android).

Comment: I think Fennec would honor `new Services.wm.getMostRecentWindow('navigator:browser').WebSocket` as well.

Comment: @paa That will work too (for now), but you'll need some extra parentheses to make clear that `getMostRecentWindow` is not the constructor, but WebSocket, so `new (Services.wm.getMostRecentWindow('navigator:browser').WebSocket)(...)`

Comment: @paa thank you so much, that was really helpful, it saved us so much effort!